# How to push datastream to kafka topic by retaining the order using string method in Flink Kafka Problem

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to create a `JSON` dataset every `500 ms` and want to push it to the `Kafka` topic so that I can set up some windows in the downstream and perform computations. Below is my code:

```
package KafkaAsSource

import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.{FlinkKafkaProducer}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KeyedSerializationSchemaWrapper


import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.util.{Optional, Properties}

object PushingDataToKafka {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setMaxParallelism(256)
    env.enableCheckpointing(5000)
    val stream: DataStream[String] = env.fromElements(createData())

    stream.addSink(sendToTopic(stream))
  }

  def getProperties(): Properties = {
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")

    return properties
  }

  def createData(): String = {
    val minRange: Int = 0
    val maxRange: Int = 1000
    var jsonData = ""
    for (a <- minRange to maxRange) {
      jsonData = "{\n  \"id\":\"" + a + "\",\n  \"Category\":\"Flink\",\n  \"eventTime\":\"" + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(LocalDateTime.now) + "\"\n  \n}"
      println(jsonData)
      Thread.sleep(500)
    }
    return jsonData
  }

  def sendToTopic(): Properties = {
    val producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer[String](
      "topic"
      ,
      new KeyedSerializationSchemaWrapper[String](new SimpleStringSchema())
      ,
      getProperties(),
      FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE
    )
    return producer
  }
}
```

It gives me below error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SinkFunction[String]
    stream.addSink(sendToTopic())
```

**Modified Code:**

```
object FlinkTest {

  def main(ars: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()
    env.setMaxParallelism(256)
    var stream = env.fromElements("")
    //env.enableCheckpointing(5000)
    //val stream: DataStream[String] = env.fromElements("hey mc", "1")

    val myProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer[String](
      "maddy", // target topic
      new KeyedSerializationSchemaWrapper[String](new SimpleStringSchema()), // serialization schema
      getProperties(), // producer config
      FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    val minRange: Int = 0
    val maxRange: Int = 10
    var jsonData = ""
    for (a <- minRange to maxRange) {
      jsonData = "{\n  \"id\":\"" + a + "\",\n  \"Category\":\"Flink\",\n  \"eventTime\":\"" + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(LocalDateTime.now) + "\"\n  \n}"
      println(a)
      Thread.sleep(500)
      stream = env.fromElements(jsonData)
      println(jsonData)
      stream.addSink(myProducer)
    }

    env.execute("hey")
  }

  def getProperties(): Properties = {
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
    return properties
  }
  /*
  def createData(): String = {
    val minRange: Int = 0
    val maxRange: Int = 10
    var jsonData = ""
    for (a <- minRange to maxRange) {
      jsonData = "{\n  \"id\":\"" + a + "\",\n  \"Category\":\"Flink\",\n  \"eventTime\":\"" + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(LocalDateTime.now) + "\"\n  \n}"
      Thread.sleep(500)
    }
    return jsonData
  }
  */

}
```

`Modified Code` gives me the data in the Kafka topic but it doesn't retain the order. What am I doing wrong here in the loops? Also, had to change the version of Flink to `1.12.2` from `1.13.5`.

I was initially using `Flink` `1.13.5`, `Connectors` and `Scala` of `2.11`. What exactly I am missing over here?

Comment: I tried with the latest flink version i.e `1.14.2` as well but still no luck. I am trying to use `KafkaSink` method but am unable to use it in `Scala`.

Comment: You missing `env.execute("jobName")` statement in main method I think.

Comment: And your error is quite explicit: your `sendToTopic()` method return type is **Any** when it should be something like `FlinkKafkaProducer[String]`

Comment: @Niko Thanks for the response.  I have tried everything before posting the question including the suggestions recommended by you. I think I am still missing something. I tried as suggested in the documentation as well but, no help.

Comment: I think there is a problem while creating datastream from the method which returns `String`.

Comment: You using `return` in your methods it changes the meaning of your program, and you should never use it. Read [here](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html) why

Comment: So, how can I segregate the logic under different methods while retaining the order in the Kafka topics?

Comment: I have added the modified code part. When I used a consumer shell to read the data from the Kafka topic, it is not giving me the data in the order I had sent. What properties am I missing?

Comment: The problem is, the sink method is not adding data one by one. I am able to see the data in the consumer only when the program execution is finished. What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things about this loop:

```scala
for (a <- minRange to maxRange) {
    jsonData = 
      "{\n  \"id\":\"" + a + "\",\n  \"Category\":\"Flink\",\n  \"eventTime\":\""
      + DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        .format(LocalDateTime.now) + "\"\n  \n}"
    println(a)
    Thread.sleep(500)
    stream = env.fromElements(jsonData)
    println(jsonData)
    stream.addSink(myProducer)
}
```

- The sleep is happening in the Flink client, and only affects how long it takes the client to assemble the job graph before submitting it to the cluster. It has no effect on how the job runs.
- This loop is creating 10 separate pipelines that will run independently, in parallel, all producing to the same Kafka topic. Those pipelines are going to race against each other.

---

To get the behavior you're looking for (a global ordering across a single pipeline) you'll want to produce all of the events from a single source (in order, of course), and run the job with a parallelism of one. Something like this would do it:

```scala
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{StreamExecutionEnvironment, _}

object FlinkTest {

  def main(ars: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()
    env.setParallelism(1)

    val myProducer = ...
    val jsonData = (i: Long) => ...

    env.fromSequence(0, 9)
      .map(i => jsonData(i))
      .addSink(myProducer)

      env.execute()
  }
}
```

You can leave maxParallelism at 256 (or at its default value of 128); it's not particularly relevant here. The maxParallelism is the number of hash buckets that `keyBy` will hash the keys into, and it defines an upper limit on the scalability of the job.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, David. How can I make it sequential under a single pipeline? What would be the best way to achieve what I need? What exactly should I change?

Comment: How can I maintain the order when consuming data when I try to read data from the shell?

Comment: Is it because of the `maxParallelism` method set in my code that is creating different pipelines?

Comment: I tried setting up with parallelism `1` but It gave me different errors. So, yeah I understood your point conceptually. However, when I tried to code it gave me the error. ` val jsonData = (i: Long) => "{\n  \"id\":\"" + i + "\",\n  \"Category\":\"Flink\",\n  \"eventTime\":\"" + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(LocalDateTime.now) + "\"\n  \n}"
    env.fromSequence(0, 9)
      .map(i => jsonData(i))
      .addSink(myProducer)`

Comment: `overloaded method value map with alternatives:
  [R](x$1: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction[java.lang.Long,R], x$2: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[R])org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator[R] <and>
  [R](x$1: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction[java.lang.Long,R])org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator[R]
 cannot be applied to (scala.Long => String)
      .map(i => jsonData(i))`

Comment: Well, if you just want to get something working and not fight with scala, you could use `env.fromElements(jsonData(0), jsonData(1), ...)`. But it could be all you need is `import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._`

Comment: I made sure my example compiles and runs.

Comment: I figured it out. My imports were incorrect which was causing the problem. I just have one doubt. In my consumer shell, I got the data once the code completed its execution. I didn't receive the records as the code was writing it to the topic? Why is it so? Am I still missing something from a concepts perspective?

Comment: The FlinkKafkaProducer only commits transactions during checkpointing. So if the kafka consumer shell is configured to read committed, it will see the records being produced as batches being committed together.

Comment: How can I achieve that, David? This is not the behavior I wanted actually. It should be streaming instead of batch. So can you suggest me?

Comment: This is Flink streaming. The only way to achieve exactly-once results when writing to Kafka is to use Kafka transactions, which has this effect. But you can decrease the checkpoint interval so that the transactions are smaller and committed more frequently.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, David. Will check it out and will post a new question if I still need it that way. Thank you so much for taking time out to help me :)

Comment: You're welcome. And btw, if latency is important, perhaps you'd be better off doing the windowing and other computations in the same job.

Comment: Yeah, I will be doing windowing on the consumer side may be of `2 secs`. I used `At-Least-Once` semantic to get my behavior for now on the producer side.

Comment: Can you help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70500023/typeinformation-in-flink-to-compare-the-datatypes-dynamically/70513324#70513324

Comment: The answer someone gave already is a good one.