# TypeInformation in Flink

Tags: scala, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a pipeline in a place where data is being sent from `Flink` to `Kafka` topic in a `JSON` format. I was also able to get it from the Kafka topic and was able to get the JSON attributes as well. Now, like `scala reflect` classes where I can also compare the data type at runtime, I was trying to do the same thing in Fink using `TypeInformation` where I can set some predefined format and whatever data is being read from topic should go under this `Validation` and should be passed or failed accordingly.
I have a data like below:.
`{"policyName":"String", "premium":2400, "eventTime":"2021-12-22 00:00:00" }`

For my problem, I came across a couple of examples in `Flink's book` where it is mentioned how to create a `TypeInformation variable` but there was nothing mentioned on how to use it so I tried my way:

```
    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()

    val tupleType: TypeInformation[(String, String, String)] =
    Types.TUPLE[(String, Int, String)]
    println(tupleType.getTypeClass)
    
    src.map(v => v)
      .map { x =>
        val policyName: String = objectMapper.readTree(x).get("policyName").toString()
        val premium: Int = objectMapper.readTree(x).get("premium").toString().toInt
        val eventTime: String = objectMapper.readTree(x).get("eventTime").toString()
        if ((policyName, premium, eventTime)== tupleType.getTypeClass) {
          println("Good Record: " + (policyName, premium, eventTime))
        }
        else {
          println("Bad Record: " + (id, category, eventTime))
        }
      }
```

Now if I pass the input as below to the flink kafka producer:

```
{"policyName":"whatever you feel like","premium":"4000","eventTime":"2021-12-20 00:00:00"}
```

It should give me the expected output as a `"Bad record" and the tuple` since the datatype of premium is String and not Long/Int.

If a pass the input as below:

```
{"policyName":"whatever you feel like","premium":4000,"eventTime":"2021-12-20 00:00:00"}
```

It should give me the output as `"Good Record" and the tuple`

But according to my code, it is always giving me the else part.

If I create a `datastream` variable and store the results of the above `map` and then compare like below then it gives me the correct result:

```
if (tupleType == datas.getType()) { //where 'datas' is a datastream
      print("Good Records")
    } else {
      println("Bad Records")
    }
```

But I want to send the `good/bad` records to a `different stream` or maybe can directly be inserted in the `Cassandra` table. So, that is why I am using loops for identifying the records one by one. Is my way correct? What would be the best practice considering what I am trying to achieve?

Based on **Dominik's** inputs, I tried creating my ow `CustomDeserializer` class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

class sample extends DeserializationSchema[String] {
  override def deserialize(message: Array[Byte]): Tuple3[Int, String, String] = {
    val data = new String(message,
      StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    val id: Int = objectMapper.readTree(data).get("id").toString().toInt
    val category: String = objectMapper.readTree(data).get("Category").toString()
    val eventTime: String = objectMapper.readTree(data).get("eventTime").toString()
    return (id, category, eventTime)

  }

  override def isEndOfStream(t: String): Boolean = ???

  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[String] = return TypeInformation.of(classOf[String])
}
```

I wanna try to implement something like below:

```
src.map(v => v)
      .map { x =>
        if (new sample().deserialize(x)==true) {
          println("Good Record: " + (id, category, eventTime))
        }
        else {
          println("Bad Record: " + (id, category, eventTime))
        }
      }
```

But the input is in `Array[Bytes]` form. So how can I implement it? Where exactly I am going wrong? What needs to be modified? This is my first ever attempt in Flink Scala custom classes.

**Inputs Passed:**  [Inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8ZQ3.jpg)

Comment: Can You elaborate a little bit on what's the expected behaviour for the described data?

Comment: I will the check the datatype of the attributes. Like if the value for premium comes as string, i will send it to a separate stream which will be used by another downstream code and will be inserted into some NoSql dB.

Comment: Its like checking for good records and bad records. If the incoming data has the expected type of attributes data (for eg: Long/Int for `Premium` then consider it as good record) ,then send it to some table.

Comment: Is there a reason why You don't do this as part of JSON parsing ?

Comment: I used Jackson's `JsonNode` and `ObjectMapper` for getting the attributes values. So, you mean while fetching these attributes, I should perform a check there itself for data types ? I am new to Flink so wanted to do it the Flink way that's why I thought of `TypeInformation`

Comment: I have edited the question with my attempt.

Comment: Is the type known or do You want to support multiple different types ?

Comment: Assume that I know the types of the 3 attributes for now.

Comment: I have modified the question with the input and output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think that using `TypeInformation` to do what You want is best idea. You can simply use something like `ProcessFunction` that will accept a JSON `String` and then use the `ObjectMapper` to deserialize JSON to class with the expected structure. You can output the correctly deserialized objects from the `ProcessFunction` and the Strings that failed deserialization can be apassed as side output since they will be Your `Bad Records`.

This could look like below, note that this uses Jackson scala to perform deserialization to case class. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966743/small-example-of-jackson-scala-module)

```
case class Premium(policyName: String, premium: Long, eventTime: String)

class Splitter extends ProcessFunction[String, Premium] {
  val outputTag = new OutputTag[String]("failed")

  def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Either[String, T] = {
    Try {
      lazy val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
      mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
      mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
      mapper.readValue[T](json)
    } match {
      case Success(x) => Right(x)
      case Failure(err) => {
        Left(json)
      }
    }
  }
  override def processElement(i: String, context: ProcessFunction[String, Premium]#Context, collector: Collector[Premium]): Unit = {
    fromJson(i) match {
      case Right(data) => collector.collect(data)
      case Left(json) => context.output(outputTag, json)
    }
  }
}
```

Then You can use the outputTag to get the side output data from the stream to get incorrect records.

Comment: Could you please share an snippet on how to do it?

Comment: Can you have a look at my code and guide me?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will take time to process your code since I am a newbie but how can I use this class's methods in my map method to test its good and bad records. How can I call those methods?

Comment: The `Splitter` is a process function so You can do smth like `streeam.process(new Splitter())` in Flink.

Comment: Ok cool. let me test it and where should I add the print statement for good and bad records? Inside success and failure?.

Comment: I have added print statements in your process element code:  `case Right(data) => {
        collector.collect(data)
        println("Good Records: " + data)
      }


      case Left(json) => {
        context.output(outputTag, json)
        println("Bad Records: " + json)
      }` and passed `{"id":"1000","premium":29999,"eventTime":"2021-12-22 00:00:00"}
` and it is giving me bad records as the output instead of good records as the print output.

Comment: Could you please help me with this?

Comment: I tried changing the state from `false` to `true` but didn't help. Any suggestions pls?

Comment: The record You passed is incorrect as `{"id":"1000","premium":29999,"eventTime":"2021-12-22 00:00:00"}` doesn't match case class schema.

Comment: I changed the variable name from `"policyName"` to `"id"` and then passed the data still it is giving me a bad record.

Comment: I have added the inputs passed at the bottom of the post. Please check and let me know what exactly I am missing.

Comment: You need to read on Scala and exception handling otheriwse this won't make any sense.

Comment: I am new to Scala but could you please atleast give me hints what exactly have to be added so that I can focus on that and implement it accordingly.

Comment: For better performance, instantiate an ObjectMapper once instead of creating a new one for each record.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DavidAnderson. After a lot of research, I found out that this Parser doesn't have a strict mode within it so what is happening is if I pass some string value for the first attribute, still it is giving me a good record instead of a bad one. Any other suggestions pls?